# Is there a name for this result in planar geometry?

Tags: reference-request, terminology, euclidean-geometry

I found out that the following statement is fairly easy to prove:

> Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be thee distinct points in the plane. Let $S_{AB}$ be the circle that has the line segment $AB$ as a diameter, and similarly $S_{AC}$. Let $L_{BC}$ be the line that goes through $B$ and $C$. Then the circles $S_{AB}$ and $S_{AC}$ and the line $L_{BC}$ all go through the same point. (This happens to be the point on $L_{BC}$ closest to $A$.)

Does this result have a name?
Or is there a well-known theorem about essentially the same construction?
I do not recall ever encountering it, but I don't believe I'm the first one to realize it.

**Note:**
I'm not looking for a proof of the claim.
If you want to see a proof, ask me.

Comment: The all pass through the feet of the altitude from $A$, but I do not think this lemma has a special name.

Comment: The altitute of *what* from $\;A\;$ to *where*?

Comment: @Timbuc, I think he means the altitude of the triangle $ABC$ from $A$ to the line $L_{BC}$. The comment appears to be essentially a restatement of my parenthetical remark at the end of the theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Lets call the point you found $X$

Via Thales' theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27_theorem  ) you can proof that that $\angle AXB $  and $\angle AXC $ are right angles (with bases $AB$ and $AC$ )

that means that $AX$ is an altitude line.

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude_%28triangle%29

so you could call point X the foot of the altitude from point A

Not sure if it has a special name. (I do doubt it)

Comment: Thanks, but this does not really answer my question. I know the geometric meaning of $X$ but I don't know a name for it or the result that the three objects intersect at one point (the point $X$). What I'm most interested in is the name of the result (if it exists); I didn't even ask for a name for the point.

Comment: I did some looking around, but could not find a name (not in Heaths translation of Euclid's elements but that doesn't even mention orthocenter ) Guess you need to look for the discoverer of the orthocenter, but could not find who that was .

Comment: I did ask Kimberling, Clark (maintainer of the  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopedia_of_Triangle_Centers, http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html ) about this he wrote me the point is the **A-vertex of the orthic triangle**.

as written before I don't know a name for the theorem but do see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1076041/who-discovered-the-orthocenter-of-a-triangle?lq=1 and the links provided there.

Comment: Thanks. Now I know the name of the point, at least in English. I guess I'll have to accept that the result (in the form I stated it) has no specific name, although it is related to well known theorems.

Comment: see also http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=1184065 and others on the otho centre (scroll down for more messages with the same title)