# who discovered the orthocenter of a triangle?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, math-history

I tried to answer [Is there a name for this result in planar geometry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075509/is-there-a-name-for-this-result-in-planar-geometry/1075956?noredirect=1#comment2188840_1075956) and wanted to go back to the first mention of the orthocenter (or even the altitude of a triangle, but i did draw a complete blank.

Orthocenter or even altitude is not mentioned in Euclid's elements (Heath's translation)

it is also not mentioned in 
Heath, T.L. (1921). A History of Greek Mathematics: From Thales to Euclid I. Oxford.
http://www.archive.org/details/cu31924008704219

So when was it discovered?

(please add references)

Comment: "altitude is not mentioned in Euclid's elements" Doesn't Book 6 Def 4 count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`The three altitudes of any triangle are concurrent at the orthocenter H (Durell 1928). This fundamental fact did not appear anywhere in Euclid's Elements.`

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ — [Source](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Altitude.html).

---

`The name was invented by Besant and Ferrers in 1865 while walking on a road leading out of Cambridge, England in the direction of London (Satterly 1962).`

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ — [Source](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Orthocenter.html).

Answer (score 1):

[This web page](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/Chapple.shtml) discusses the matter of who first proved that a triangle's altitudes concur. It states that "The timing of the first proof is still an open question; it is believed, though, that even the great Gauss saw it necessary to prove the fact. The earliest known proof was given by William Chapple (1718-1781) in 1749."

[This web page](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/altitudes.shtml) on proofs of this result gives Chapple's proof and cites it as follows: "It comes from the Miscellanea Curiosa Mathematica, Number IX, edited by Francis Holliday and published by Cave - I understand that this publication was launched in 1745, with two issues a year, which would place the publication date in 1749, the year of publication of a collected edition".